# "We're sorry, but something went wrong" in Rails app related to file upload. How do I debug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, passenger, passenger-nginx

I have a Rails 5 app that contains a lot of basic scaffold-like code. A bunch of models with associated controllers and views for basic CRUD operations. It runs under passenger and with nginx as a front end.

I have this app running on a production server, where everything is fine. But I also have it on a testing server, where one model (let's call it "Foo")'s **new** function fails. If I try to create a new model object, when I hit save (submit the form), I *was* getting a 404 from nginx. The URL shown in the location bar is what is expected (https://host.domain/foos). I have since fixed that nginx error, and now I get **We're sorry, but something went wrong** from Rails (or is it Passenger?)

The thing about Foo is that it contains 3 file uploads. Same thing is happening in another part of the app that tries to take a file upload from the user (all using the `file_field` method on the form in the view). I feel sure this is the critical factor.

But when I check the Passenger log file, and Rails log file, there's nothing there. I also checked the output of `journalctl -u passenger` (this is RHEL7), and nothing. How can I find where an error message is reported? Recall that everything works on my prod server that has almost identical configuration. Thanks.

Comment: Without any code to work from, we're all just guessing in the dark. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: "almost identical configuration" between 'prod' and 'test' forgets that Rails is environment aware. Look for changes in `test.rb` vs. `production.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

Without any real code to look at, I'm just guessing.

A few ideas:

- You say "test" server, but then other things you say make it sound like it persists, not just spins up for running a test suite, then shuts off. In the test environment, Rails truncates and runs database writes within a transaction it can roll back. So records don't exist to be found again, as one might expect to happen after submitting a new record form. Redirecting to an index or show view will fail to find that record.
- Try running that "test" server as a "staging" environment so Rails actually persists data to the database.
- Ensure you have the database actually created on this test server (e.g. your `database.yml` file)